# OLEDB Parameterized Query

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-access, oledb

```
public void LoadDB()
{
    string FileName = @"c:\asdf.accdb";
    string query = "SELECT ID, Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID=? AND Field1=?";
    string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName;

    OleDbConnection odc = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
    dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,odc);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = 1234;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.BSTR, 5).Value ="asdf";

    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    ds = new DataSet();
    dAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

I'm trying to use parametrized query to bind the access file into the datagridview. It finds the column names fine, but the contents are empty.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does you query return rows when you manually run it from Access and input above given parameters?

Comment: Your first parameter is an integer, but you are setting it as a string.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel Sorry, can you clarify? I'm not sure if I understood your question. What I do know is if I use OleDBCommandBuilder instead of parametrized query, the whole things works perfectly.

Comment: @LarsTech Fixed. Still doesn't work.

Comment: consider creating a query in Access with your sql and two parameter fields and then call the query instead of passing the sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my test program, the ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count datatable actually had 1 row returned (as there was one row in my test database that matched the query itself). If you put a break on this line you should be able to see whether or not data is getting into the datatable in the first place. Try this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

What does the front end binding of dataGridView1 look like? Running the query in Access could shed some light on the situation too.

Comment: As you suggested, I put a breakpoint on the datatable and while the data is getting the columns, it's not getting the rows. What could be a possible cause?

Comment: So ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0? Have you run the SQL from within Access to verify the output as well?

Comment: Never mind, it was my SQL Query that was problematic. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how the parameterized queries work with CSharp, OleDB.

```
try
{
    connw.Open();
    OleDbCommand command;
    command = new OleDbCommand(
        "Update Deliveries " +
        "SET Deliveries.EmployeeID = ?, Deliveries.FIN = ?, Deliveries.TodaysOrders = ? , connw);
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@EMPID", Convert.ToDecimal(empsplitIt[1])));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FIN", truckSplit[1].ToString()));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@TodaysOrder", "R"));
    catchReturnedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();//Commit   
    connw.Close();

}
catch (OleDbException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "OleDb Exception");
}
```

This will work with any sql statement, you must assign the question mark "?" to each parameter, and then below you must create the parameters and add them in the order of how you laid out the question marks to get the right data into the right field.

Comment: Thanks for the example...the documentation on this is terrible.

Comment: Agreed, I fought through the depths of the internet to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try without specifying column size in parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1234;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.BSTR).Value ="asdf";
```