# Getting a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing a code and getting a syntax error that I dont know from where that comes. This is the code I am using:

```
string u = "select uniqcode from login where users='" + textBoxX1.Text + "' ";
```

and this is the error I am getting:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''select uniqcode
>   from login where users='someuser' ''."
>   (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException)A System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
>   was thrown: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   ''select uniqcode from login where users='someuser' ''."

Comment: You should bind parameters instead of concatenating SQL string, because  user can write in textbox sth like `'; DROP TABLE ... ;--`

Comment: Why is the column `users` plural? Do you store multiple users comma separated??

Comment: what do you mean?! would you please elaborate it more ?!

Comment: SQL Parameters(OLEDB): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat: he means sql parameters, read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.Parameters(v=VS.110).aspx (@lex: it's a `OleDbCommand`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good point, i didn't read the error message thoroughly enough.

Comment: So, which way I have to use?! I really got confused ?!

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat Did you try something `u = "select uniqcode from login where users=?";` and then `u.Parameters.Add("@users", OleDbType.VarChar).value = textBoxX1.Text;`

Comment: @Afshin Haghighat Is the uniqcode  is interger of string?

Comment: @LibinCJacob what do you mean?!

Comment: @Afshin Haghighat  What  Is the type of field "uniqcode" in your database

Comment: @LibinCJacob type is `text` for `uniqcode`

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that textbox text is containing single quote ('). If yes then replace single quote (') by two single quotes ('')

Otherwise, try to execute it using sql parameters.

Comment: No, it the textbox' value doesn't contain any quotes as you can see from the OP's description: `select uniqcode from login where users='someuser' `. The quotes are part of the query...
I think this should be rather a comment than an answer as it won't help the OP. You tell him to use SQL Parameters; then show a short example as he obviously has no clue how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
string u = "select login.uniqcode from [login] where users='" + textBoxX1.Text.Trim() + "'";
```

Comment: still the same error `{"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''select login.uniqcode from [login] where users='someuser'''."}`

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat if you will post complete code then it will be easy to figure out the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Since your error represent that you are using `OleDb` connection then you may use following code. This will avoid `SQL Injection` as well. However you may need to work a bit to following piece into your code.

```
u = "select uniqcode from login where users=?"; 

u.Parameters.Add("@users", OleDbType.VarChar).value = textBoxX1.Text;
```

You may see examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query)

Comment: Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Parameters' and no extension method 'Parameters' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat Ofcourse it won't work. I wrote it as well that you would need to work a bit with my code.. and on comments section.. I asked you to show your more code so that we can help.. Can you show more code around this line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to firstly [read and understand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee796775(v=cs.20).aspx) there are SQL syntax limitations in OleDB.

**"A single quote must be escaped with another single quote."**

But really, **forget** single quotes.

Read more about using OleDB [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1449/OLE-DB-First-steps). It's ancient technology anyway, so I would get away from OleDB and have your database ported over to SQL Server or MySQL.

However, what you may need is something like this...

```
try
{
    connw.Open();
    OleDbCommand command;
    command = new OleDbCommand(
        "SELECT *" +
        "FROM tableA WHERE Deliveries.EmployeeID = ?, Deliveries.FIN = ?, Deliveries.TodaysOrders = ? , connw);
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@EMPID", Convert.ToDecimal(empsplitIt[1])));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FIN", truckSplit[1].ToString()));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@TodaysOrder", "R"));
    catchReturnedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();//Commit   
    connw.Close();

}
catch (OleDbException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "OleDb Exception");
}
```

Golden rule of database coding, is never pass a variable directly into the SQL statement like you've done above. That is opening yourself for SQL Injection big time.