# Access won't save input

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I looked on Yt, Google etc. I tried 5 solutions and nothing. I put txt to the text box, it shows in list box but dont go to access.

In short words.

```
 private void addAF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


         if (aFInput.Text != "") {

            string q = "insert into AFs (AFNumber,SendDate,Notes) values ('"+aFInput.Text.ToString()+"','"+DateTime.Now+"', '"+notes.Text.ToString()+"')";
            dosomemagic(q);
            aFInput.Text = null;

        }

    }
    private void dosomemagic(String q)
    {

        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
            loaddata();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cnn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ANLPA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=AFdbB03.mdb;";
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        loaddata();
    }

    private void loaddata()
    {
        AFList.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            string q = "select * from AFs";
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cnn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    AFList.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    keyList.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());

                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            cnn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug that code?

Comment: Did you have the database file listed between your project files? If yes what is the property "Copy to Output Directory"?

Comment: Code is running without errors or warnings. File is visible in my files I added database with add database. Program show in list box all data from db.

Comment: @Venator what is the value of the property Copy to Output directory of your MDB file listed in your project files?

Comment: Property is "Copy always"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app runs, it runs from the folder `BIN\DEBUG` and you add your record in the database copied in that folder by Visual Studio when you start your debug session. If your file has the property `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy Always` then, everytime you start a debug session, Visual Studio copies the MDB file from your project folder to your Output Directory (BIN\DEBUG or x86 variant)

In this way, your code writes correctly, but at the next run your data disappears because the file has been substituted by Visual Studio

Set the property `Copy To Output directory` to `Copy Never` or `Copy if Newer`

As a side note, please take a bit of your time to learn how to use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query). Your code actually works, but what happen if your notes textbox contains a single quote in its Text property? The code will crash with a syntax error. But this is the minor of your problems. There is a well know hacking technique called [Sql Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx) that could destroy the data in your database.

Comment: The property Copy if Newer  partly solved my problem because now when after rebuild solution everythin is still there but when I'm opening Access file its not there and after rebulid it disappear  from listbox too.

Comment: The Copy never property is worser because it shows me just after rebuild "can not find the file"

Comment: Did you have the MDB file in the <projectfolder>\BIN\DEBUG folder (or x86)? Once copied the first time it is not deleted by Visual Studio Try setting copy if newer

Comment: Yes I just checked that and it is in \bin\debug folder. copy if newer couse the problem with opening the file. It's ok to the open but then its clear again. It looks like opening the file deletes all changes.

Comment: VS has everything in OneDrive so everything is in cloud so maby that couse all the problems?

Comment: I think that you should avoid this setting with OneDrive. I would set the property to COPY NEVER  and be sure to have the file in the BIN\DEBUG folder. Another solution is to change the connection string adding a path to a private folder where you keep your database so there will be no interference from Visual Studio

Comment: I'm gonna sit to that tomorrow today I'm tired I'm fighting with c# from 6 am but It's good to learn something new in C# and English as well. I just checked the Access file from the debug folder and everything is there but when I done the same with the core file in project it disappear. Thx very much. I think that it's gonna work now.