# How to update database record vs12 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2010

Hi I'm having troubles making a update button for my website I've tried many methods but can't seem to figure it out. I would like the user to enter the ID number of the client they wish to update then fill the text box according to the columns they wish to change.

Here's my code:

```
private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    String connString;
    connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Wisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite3\registration-Db.mdb";

    return new OleDbConnection(connString);
}

protected void clientUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Wisal/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite3\registration-Db.mdb");

    cn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("(Update client set id = " + txt_id.Text + " ,[name] ='" + txt_name.Text + " ,[password] ='" + txt_password.Text +" where id= '" + txt_id.Text + "",cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    }      
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    String connString;
    connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Wisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite3\registration-Db.mdb";

    return new OleDbConnection(connString);

}

protected void clientUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();

    myConnection.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("(Update client set id = " + txt_id.Text + " ,[name] ='" + txt_name.Text + " ,[password] ='" + txt_password.Text +" where id= '" + txt_id.Text + "",myConnection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

With this one I get "Syntax error in union query."

I have tried this too:

```
protected void clientUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();

    myConnection.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update client set [name] = ? [password] = ? where id= ?", myConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txt_id.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txt_name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txt_password.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
    }

    }
```

Comment: You should catch for any threw exception, but it seems that your sql string is missing many ' (single quote).

Comment: You have several huge security problems. You need to use parameterized queries, and passwords should never be stored in plaintext in a database (use salted one-way hashes instead).

Comment: Have a look at your CommandText, it is most likely the cause of your exception.

Comment: Why is there an opening parenthesis at the beginning of your update statement?  That should not be there.

Comment: The order of the parameters are important.  And what is the error you are getting.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '? [password] = ?'. @kiwiPiet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your code slightly:

```
private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    var connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Wisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite3\registration-Db.mdb";

    return new OleDbConnection(connString);
}

protected void clientUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var myConnection = GetConnection())
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        // You should be using a parameterized query here
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update client set [name] = ?, [password] = ? where id = ?", myConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txt_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", txt_password.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", txt_id.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

- Use using blocks around disposable objects
- Check your SQL, no need to update id if that is your primary key and be careful of single quotes.  Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: [OLEDB Parameterized Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query)

Comment: I  will edit my code and show you how i did it because i'm getting errors when i do that

Answer (score 0):

Your single quote doesn't match?

Is your `id` field of type int or string? I assume it's of type int. And you don't need to update `id` field since it's the same as the value in where clause.

Try this one:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update client set [name] ='" + txt_name.Text + "' ,[password] ='" + txt_password.Text +"' where id= " + txt_id.Text,myConnection);
```

Comment: it's strange once the information has been updated the gridview doesn't update the database even when i refresh the page hmm.

Comment: when I update the record for example i update the name column not the "password" then the password column data will dissappear. any idea on how to resolve this? @Ricky