# Sending String from Database from one Form to another

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm trying to send a string and a bool from one form to another. The string I'm trying to send is the PayrollNo where the name is present also in the ODeDb Database.

Here's the code I'm using but its not working,

```
private void BtnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
    string Query = "SELECT PayrollNo, FirstName, LastName FROM [Employee] WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) =" +DropBoxEmp.Text;
    EmployeeDetails form = new EmployeeDetails();
    using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
    {
        Conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand GetPayRoll = new OleDbCommand(Query, Conn);
        string NewPayroll = (GetPayRoll.ExecuteNonQuery()).ToString();
        Conn.Close();
        form.PassValuePayrollNo = NewPayroll;
        form.PassEditing = true;
        form.Tag = this;
        form.Show(this);
        Hide();
    }
}
```

I get the error :

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression '(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) =Gary Lindsay'.

DropBoxEMP is a comboBox populated with the first and last names appended from [Employee].
Gary Lindsay is the appended firstName and lastName from the Table [Employee]
How should I change my code to send the string correctly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When you use a parameter to supply the value you 1) will fix the problem; 2) prevent sql injection attacks

Comment: How would I edit my code to do this?

Comment: This question has an example of using parameterized queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect this happens because you forget to use single quotes for your

```
(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) =" +DropBoxEmp.Text
```

should be

```
(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) = '" + DropBoxEmp.Text + "'"
```

#### But do not use this way.

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your command as you did for your connection. This statement provides an auto-dispose method so you *don't* need to close your connection manually.

Also using `ExecuteNonQuery` for a `SELECT` statement does not make sense. This method *just* executes your query. It does *not* return any data or something.

If you wanna return some data from your query, you can use `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteScalar` if your query returns only one row which I think it is in your case.

```
string NewPayroll = (string)GetPayRoll.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Sonar, you never fail to help me out, thanks a bunch!! I'll mark this as an answer as soon as I can!

Comment: I've deleted my comment as it makes no sense at all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a parameter to supply the value you 1) will fix the (first) problem; 2) prevent sql injection attacks (work out what your concatenated query would do when you add the missing quotes but want to get the details about "Paddy O'Malley").

I don't use OleDb much, so this may contain errors, but will provide the direction:

first: change the query to use a parameter:

```
string Query = "SELECT PayrollNo, FirstName, LastName FROM [Employee]"+
 " WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) = ?";
```

Then add that parameter plus value to the command object:

```
GetPayRoll.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DropBoxEmp.Text;
```

and then execute the query, after noticing the comments about that from Soner Gönül.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I've done almost, Thanks for the help!