# Access to SQL Server syntax changeover

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ms-access, database-migration

I recently moved a project that I made from Access to MS SQLServer, but of course this means I need to change some of the code in my SQL statements.

I have this subroutine where I am getting all records where the field `DateRenew` is within 30 days... How do I convert this to SQL? At the moment I get the following error message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in MaintenanceControl.exe
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '#'.

```
    Private Sub btn30Days_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn30Days.Click

    Dim td As String
    Dim sd As String
    sd = Format(Today.AddDays(31), "MM/dd/yyyy")
    td = Format(Today, "MM/dd/yyyy")

    Try
        sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblContracts WHERE DateRenew BETWEEN #" & sd & "# AND #" & td & "#;"
        conAd = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        conset = New DataSet
        conAd.Fill(conset)
        ugModules.DataSource = conset

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        MsgBox("Failed to retrieve contract information from database, refer to error log")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to switch your program to SqlServer why still using OleDb? There are the classes in SqlClient that are specific for Sql Server. However dates in SqlServer are not prefixed/postfixed with # and in any case you should stop using string concatenations but use parameters so no more hassle with parsing differences between sql server or access or <put your database name here>

Comment: Look at using *parameters* rather than concatenating strings to create your queries - it'd help here because you then avoid taking `DateTime` values, converting them to strings, and then forcing the server to convert them back into `DateTime` values - such chains of conversions can *introduce* formatting issues that wouldn't exist if you use the proper types throughout, which parameterization allows (you also learn to avoid SQL injection at the same time)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hi, most of my projects do have parameterised queries, however with this particular one I wasn't quite sure how to, as `DateRenew` never gets declared, and I'm not sure how to declare it when it's a database field, so I was hoping there would be a way to just convert this into SQL syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier and less error-prone is to directly use the date functions of SQL Server.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblContracts WHERE DateRenew BETWEEN 
       CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, 31, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))"
```

(line break for readability)

If it doesn't matter that `GETDATE()` includes the current time, you can leave out the `CONVERT(DATE, ...)` parts.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dim td As String
Dim sd As String
sd = Format(Today.AddDays(31), "yyyyMMdd")
td = Format(Today, "yyyyMMdd")

Try
    sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblContracts WHERE DateRenew BETWEEN ''" & sd & "'' AND ''" & td & "'';"
    conAd = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    conset = New DataSet
    conAd.Fill(conset)
    ugModules.DataSource = conset

Catch ex As Exception
    errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
    MsgBox("Failed to retrieve contract information from database, refer to error log")
End Try
```

YYYYMMDD is a date format for SQL (iso)
the # is replaced by ' (single quote) in SQL
in VB you need to enter ' as '' as an escape sequence - that is enter a single quote as TWO consequitve SINGLE quotes

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response, after using this code instead I then get an error saying `Incorrect syntax near '20160825'.` (Clearly one of the dates), is this because of the fact it gets saved with a '-' in between each part of the date?

Comment: Not sure if one needs to escape single '`' inside of double-quoted string (`"`).

Comment: I know what it is, you enter the single quotes as one single quote in VB   sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblContracts WHERE DateRenew BETWEEN '" & sd & "' AND '" & td & "'";     -- I was talking rubbish basically