# Select records by date range in Access Table From C# Application

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am developing a simple C# application for retrieving particular records from one table and insert in to another table in MS Access. Also this task ha s to be performed daily using Windows task scheduler.

The selection of records has to be done on date range to retrieve "Today created records".

My application works between [ DateTime.Today.AddDays(-100) to DateTime.Today.AddDays(0)] but, it wont work for DateTime.Today.AddDays(0) to DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)

I have done so far below.

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Tom\\Dropbox\\P2002\\p2002.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();  
        Console.WriteLine("Connected...");
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into New1 ([B ID], [Dat], [Sum]) SELECT BID, Dat, Summe FROM Bestellung Where [Datum] BETWEEN #" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(0) + "# AND #" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) + "#" ;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.AddDays(0));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Record Submitted");
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Select from one table and insert in to another table....

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp That is simply not true. This is an `INSERT SELECT` statement and a WHERE clause is appropriate. OP, can you save your SQL into a variable and `Console.Writeline` that out. Then run just the SELECT portion to troubleshoot this? I do agree that you should be parameterizing your queries, it may clear up whatever issue you are facing. [See the code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query) for an example of what that would look like for Access.

Comment: Sorry, didnt notice the nested SELECT portion

Comment: It works for - 100 to 0 days.....I can retrieve all those records for past three months. Also when i coded it initially , it worked, now only it didn't insert....

Comment: is it supposed to be '[B<space>ID]' on your insert ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is caused by the automatic conversion from the datetime values (Today and Today.AddDays(1)) into a string when you concatenate those values.

When you query MS Access on date fields with string constants, it wants the strings formatted in the "MM/dd/yyyy" way, and thus you should return a string formatted in that mode when you use it to represent your date values. Like so:

```
... Where [Datum] BETWEEN #" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ...
```

(Note that I removed the Today.AddDays(0) because it makes no sense)

but there is another way a lot more safe because it avoids any possible Sql Injection attack and more flexible because it doesn't force you to concatenate strings and use formatting options. This method is called "Parameterized query"

Here how to rewrite your code to use parameters.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(.....))
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    con.Open();  
    Console.WriteLine("Connected...");
    cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into New1 ([B ID], [Dat], [Sum]) 
         SELECT BID, Dat, Summe 
         FROM Bestellung 
         Where [Datum] BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2";
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.AddDays(0));
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Record Submitted");
}
```

Comment: Hi, it throws an error - " Non-invocable member 'OleDbCommand.Parameters' cannot be used like a method "

Comment: My bad, fixed now, should Add the parameter to the Parameters collection

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't throw any error on Parameterized query, but it says ".Net framework has stopped working" and the query is not executed well....