# Special Character in SQL Sentence

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm working with C# and a database Access.

I need execute a query, and then I build it:

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO  ivaPorcentajes(idivaTipos, idZonaEconomica, descripcion, descripcionConRe, iva, re, periodoDesde, periodoHasta, sistema) values ("
                       + "" + objIvaPorcentaje.IdivaTipo.ToString() + ","
                       + "" + objIvaPorcentaje.IdZonaEconomica.ToString() + "," 
                        + "'" + Convert.ToString( objIvaPorcentaje.Descripcion) + "'," 
                        + "'" +  Convert.ToString(objIvaPorcentaje.DescripcionConRe) + "'," 
                        + "" + objIvaPorcentaje.Iva.ToString() + "," 
                        + "" + objIvaPorcentaje.Re.ToString() + "," 
                        + "" + objIvaPorcentaje.PeriodoDesde.ToString() + "," 
                        + "" + objIvaPorcentaje.PeriodoHasta.ToString() + ","
                        + "" + objIvaPorcentaje.Sistema.ToString() + "" +
                         ");";
```

The problem is when the field "objIvaPorcentaje.DescripcionConRe" have a character Colon, (Char(44)).

Then the Sql statement gives a syntax error.

How I can do it??

Thanks

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with literal values.

Comment: Please go read up about "sql injection" and learn to never make SQL strings like this.

Comment: If you do a parametrized query, you get rid of the error you have and, as a bonus, you avoid the SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). What if some of your inputs result in `DROP TABLE ivaPorcentajes;` ?

Comment: @vasily.sib well, then we get rid of those nasty taxes! (it is a tax % related table)

Comment: Check this link on how to do [parametrized queries in access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889774/2265446) to avoid security problems like [exploits de una madre](https://es.xkcd.com/strips/exploits-de-una-madre/). Un saludo ;-)