# How to query sum from access db by date

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

i have query from my form load event that will show total sales,

[given dbase value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0yYS.png)

```cs
lbldate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
try
{
    MyConN.Open();
    OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    Cmd.Connection = MyConN;
    Cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(TotalSales) from LSales where DISTINCT SDate='" + "label7.Text" + "'";
    //OleDbDataReader ReadeR = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:  " + ex.Message);
}


but this code throwing 
>"syntax error (missing operator) in query expression `'DISTINCT SDate='16/6/2020''` 

i want to sum all `totalsales` base on date
```

Comment: You should remove DISTINCT from the query.

Comment: @chetan, remove DISTINCT  error still there, datatype mismatch

Comment: have you tried the query in sql server?

Comment: @sajid, didnt try coz im using access as database

Comment: for me, you have two issues,  @ChetanRanpariya was mentioned the first, and the second is double quote around `label7.Text`, this should work : `SELECT SUM(TotalSales) as Total FROM LSales WHERE SDate='" + label7.Text + "'"`

Comment: @Sajid, how can i get the result in my textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `distinct` is used with `select`, not `where`
2. `SDate='" + "label7.Text" + "'"` not good. If `sdate` is date-time, do

```cs
Cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(TotalSales) from LSales where SDate=?";
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@1", DateTime.Parse(label7.Text)));
```

In other words, make sure you pass date. Then you don't need to worry about type conversion. You might need though make sure that you compare date to date. Remember about minutes and seconds that can be there. [This is good reference for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query)