# Update SQL Statement Issue - No value given for one or more required parameters - Coded in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Getting the error

> 'No value given for one of more require parameters'

on the `SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line

As you can probably tell from the SQL Statement I'm trying to update the `staffPassword` value in Staff table where `staffID` = the staffID variable.

I have looked over all of the spelling of variables and database values and they're all spelt correctly.

```
  If DbConnect() And AreYouSureEdit = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then 

            Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand 
            SQLCmd.Connection = cn 

            SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff " & "SET staffPassword = @newPassword " & "WHERE staffID = @staffID"
            SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close() 

            MsgBox("Password Editting Completed.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly & MsgBoxStyle.Information) 

        ElseIf AreYouSureEdit = MsgBoxResult.No Then

            MsgBox("Password Editting Cancelled, no changes will be made.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly & MsgBoxStyle.Information) 

        End If

    Else

        MsgBox("Passwords do not match.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    End If
```

Comment: You don't appear to be creating and adding the 2 params via `SQLCmd.Parameters.Add( ... )` ?

Comment: Also afaik you need `?` not `@name` for the param placeholders.

Comment: @AlexK. I've just added SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@staffID", staffID) and SQLCmd.Paramaters.Add("@newPassword", newPassword) It doesn't produce any errors anymore although it isn't updating the database.

Comment: `System.Data.OleDbCommand` is a .NET object, this isn't VBA code hosted in Access, it's VB.NET code *querying* an Access database (right?). Your SQL statement prompts for two parameters, you need to supply a value for them. Why is the SQL command string split up and concatenated though?

Comment: As a side note, this code is very susceptible to SQL injection.   What would happen if my @newPassword contained  ''; --  (All passwords would be set to blank).   And if it contained ''; truncate table Staff,   etc.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sorry, I'm a student, my teacher won't reply right now. You are right, it is a VBA Project that queries an Access database and honestly, not too sure why I've split up the SQL Command

Comment: Access does not support named parameters over OLEDB, only positional parameters. So as Alex K. said you need to replace 'SET staffPassword = @newPassword' with 'SET staffPassword = ?'. Then add the parameters in the correct order, this is vital. It doesn't matter what you call them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048152/oledb-parameterized-query

Comment: @Sparky no, it's not. `@newPassword` is a parameter. Using parameters is exactly how you protect from SQL injection vulnerabilities. The hypothetical scenario you're suggesting happens when you concatenate *values* into the command string, and that is not what the OP is doing. Password could be anything, it will be stored as-is (which is another problem in itself, should be hashed & salted, not stored in plain text).

Comment: Thank you all! I wish to be as good as you all one day :) It's fixed now you were all right, I've added SQLCmd.AddWithValue("@staffID", staffID) etc... I'm not sure about the SET staffPassword = ? though I didn't have to do this and it works and in regards to the SQL Injection, I'll look into it, thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: @PurchaseWinRAR [XKCD #327](https://xkcd.com/327/) is a classic :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Proud to say I found that funny, on my way to becoming a software engineer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parameters to your command to pass the value for parameters. Try

```
SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET staffPassword = @newPassword WHERE staffID = @staffID"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPassword", valueforPassword);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffID", valueforStaffID);            

SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Access doesn't support named parameters over OLEDB.

Comment: @AlanB I don't know where you've heard this from because this solution has worked. It successfully Updates the database with no errors.

Comment: @AlanB that's great to know. Best wishes.

Comment: @PurchaseWinRAR ODBC and OLEDB don't support named parameters. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: @Alan B That means that the name of the Parameter is ignored, just the position it takes in the sequence of the Command Parameters you add is considered and that the sequence of the Parameters in the query must be the same. You can use whatever *name* you like. The name is irrelevant. Only the *position* matters.

Comment: @Jimi Um yes, that's what  "ODBC and OLEDB don't support named parameters" means? And I also pointed out that it is only the position that matters twice?

Comment: @Alan B Are you asking me (didn't you test it)? Yes, that's what it means. You could have a Command setup as, e.g., `[Command].Parameters.Add("@someParam", OleDbType.SomeType).Value = someValue` and in the query `"SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField = @abc`. So you can use write `@abc` instead of `@someParam`, it's the same. If you have more parameters, what matters is the sequential order in which these are added in `[Command].Parameters.Add(...)`. Naming the Parameters simply makes it easier for us when reading the query string (-> *general use comment*).

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I said above.

"
Access does not support named parameters over OLEDB, only positional parameters. So as Alex K. said you need to replace 'SET staffPassword = @newPassword' with 'SET staffPassword = ?'. Then add the parameters in the correct order, this is vital. It doesn't matter what you call them. "

Comment: @Alan B You don't need **at all** to use `?`, use whatever make the code more readable and understandable. Using a question mark makes it way less readable and way less understandable. Just keep in mind that the position determines the value set, not the name of the parameter (that's what *named parameters not supported* means, it doesn't mean that you have to use a `?`, which, BTW, IS a name. You can use whatever you want).